# Giving runif() max and min that are tibbles with multiple entries

Tags: r

Looking at the following code in R:

> theta1 <- runif(100, min=0,max=1)
>
> epsilon <- runif(100, min=theta1-1, max=theta1)

The min and max given for the epsilon variable is a tibble containing 100 entries, how can I interpret this?

Comment: I'm confused by *"is a tibble"*. What you are feeding is a vector.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. Is the code provided already correct (perhaps found in an example), and you would like someone to explain what it is doing? Or are you asking how to modify the code to generate epsilon if given a 100-row tibble with columns min and max?

Comment: The inspect() function called it a 'tibble' so I called it tibble. It's an ordered sequence of numbers. I was wondering what epsilon would be after this operation. Each entry of epsilon will be randomly drawn between the corresponding value of theta1 -1 and theta1? EG if theta1 = c(1,2,3) then epsilon would have a first element drawn from closed interval [0,1], second from [1,2] and third from [2,3]? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if this is what you are after, but if your min/max are instead given in a tibble, here is how you could generate the vector `epsilon` from those values.

```
# Number of rows to generate
n <- 100L

# Table of min/max values to use
df <- dplyr::tibble(
        max = runif(n)
        ) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(
        min = max - 1L
        )

# vector of random values
epsilon <- purrr::map_dbl(
             df$min, 
             df$max, 
             ~ runif(1L, min = .x, max = .y)
             )
```